# Unable to set up nginx correctly due to permission error

Tags: nginx

I am able to open index.html located at `/usr/share/nginx` via the IP address which is great. The nginx.conf looks like this:

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        #root         /home/intern;
        root    /usr/share/nginx;
        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
             # proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10000/;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

I have user `intern` and have access only to `/home/intern` folder and would like to route the IP address to `root    /home/intern` where I've created an index.html (and uploaded my other files) but it gives me a `505 internal server error`.

I don't have permission to upload my files in `/usr/share/nginx`. I'm not very familiar with using terminal although I can do `sudo -i` and go to root user access; if that's any help.

My problem will be fixed if I can upload my files to `/usr/share/nginx` or if the server doesn't return an error when I change the root to `/home/intern`

Any help woul dbe appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about ngnix but from other applications on linux, there is probably a group named ngnix and you (your user) has to be assigned to that group. Run *grep ngnix /etc/group* to see if there is such a group and *groups* to see to what groups your user is assigned.

Comment: Thanks but nothing shows up when running `grep ngnix /etc/group`

Comment: Sorry then, my guess was wrong and you have to wait for someone with more specific knowledge. Or, it is yust because of a spelling error in the command.

Comment: Alright. I'm assuming the user nginx needs to be given access to /home/intern but I'm unable to do it.

Comment: I have installed nginx right now and have similar problems with permissions. This could be fixed by "brute force" giving permissions to some users, but I suggest waiting for someone who know how this is supposed to be done.

Comment: I ended up giving permission like this and it worked: `chown -R elaine /usr/share/nginx`. I copied all my files there.